# Run apt-get upgrade -s in container and expect same result as when running on the host

Tags: debian, apt, kubernetes, prometheus

I would like to prepare the environment for a Docker container such that when `apt-get upgrade -s` runs inside the container its result is the same as if the command were run outside on the host. This is in the context of and in preparation for adding a text collector [`apt.sh`](https://github.com/prometheus-community/node-exporter-textfile-collector-scripts) to an existing Prometheus `node-exporter`. I am already using a Kubernetes `DaemonSet` to control such containers (pods) in a way similar to an example from GitHub [`prometheus-community/node-exporter-textfile-collector-scripts`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/prometheus/node-exporter-ds.yml).

Judging from its man page, `apt-get` works with files in `/etc/apt`, `/var/cache/apt`, and `/var/lib/apt`, and so my container mounts those read-only from the host. Currently my host and container run Debian 9 (Stretch) and Debian 10 (Buster) respectively. I account for this by running `apt-get upgrade -s` outside the container and `apt-get upgrade -s -t stretch` inside.

However the two runs still produce different results. What am I missing?

Comment: quite sure it needs /var/lib/dpkg/status unless it deems the apt cache is up to date

Answer (score 1):

Fro docker official documentation:

```
APT-GET
Probably the most common use-case for RUN is an application of apt-get. Because it installs packages, the RUN apt-get command has several gotchas to look out for.

Avoid RUN apt-get upgrade and dist-upgrade, as many of the “essential” packages from the parent images cannot upgrade inside an unprivileged container.

If a package contained in the parent image is out-of-date, contact its maintainers.
```

Comment: +1 Hmm ... but then `apt-get upgrade -s` is quite different from `apt-get upgrade`.